# How to use two locations with Geocoder rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I use [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) in Rails, but my model has two locataions (route_from, route_to). 
I can use it only for one attribute. But I won't use a both.

```
geocoded_by :address  
after_validation :geocode
```

What do I do?

Comment: What's your problem, exactly? What is causing you troubles? You should expand the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder is not really built to have handle locations in the same model. Rather than beating a skrew in with a hammer you should split your domain into two models:

```
class Journey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :route_from, class: 'Waypoint'
  has_one :route_to, class: 'Waypoint'
end

class Waypoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
  after_validation :reverse_geocode  # auto-fetch address
end
```

If you can imagine the route having more than two nodes you might want to set it up with a join model.

Comment: Thank you, but how create new Journey using this way?